# Displaying and saving records from Apex controller in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on a LWC to live within a screen flow that will allow adding of records and editing of existing records, but something is off in terms of how the data is translated back and forth. The desired fields show in `result.data` and then when added to `ERDHRecords` they are there, but as `Date__c` rather than `Date`. And for save to work correctly, I had to add a translation step. Examples of this thing I've found online have a much cleaner back and forth, so clearly I'm missing something important.

### JS controller

```
import { LightningElement,track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/CoachPortalHelperClassesEYD.getERDH';
import insertERDH from '@salesforce/apex/CoachPortalHelperClassesEYD.addERDH';
import Date_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c.Date__c';
import Hours_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c.Hours__c';
import Modality_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c.Modality__c';
import RecordID_Field from '@salesforce/schema/Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c.id';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class engagementReportHoursEntry extends LightningElement {
    @api ERid;
    @track ERDHRecord = {Id: RecordID_Field, Date : Date_FIELD, Hours : Hours_FIELD,Modality : Modality_FIELD, key : Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)};
    @track ERDHRecords = [];
    @track saveMessage = false;
    @track totalHours = 0;
    toggleSaveLabel = 'Save';
       
   @wire(getRecords, { ERid: "$ERid" }) 
   getResults(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            if(result.data.length==0){
                //this.addRow();
            } else {
                console.log(result.data);
                this.ERDHRecords = result.data;
                console.log(this.ERDHRecords);
            }
        } else {
            //this.addRow();
        }
   }        

    /*connectedCallback(){
        console.log('  === connectedCallback === ');
        this.ERDHTempRecords();
    }*/

    addRow(){
        const len = this.ERDHRecords.length;
        this.ERDHRecords.push({Date : Date_FIELD, Hours : Hours_FIELD,Modality : Modality_FIELD, key : Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)});
    }

    removeRow(event){
        const indexPos = event.currentTarget.name;
        let remList = [];
        remList = this.ERDHRecords;
        remList.splice(indexPos,1);
        this.ERDHRecords = remList;
        this.sumHours();
    }

    handleDateChange(event){
        let foundelement = this.ERDHRecords.find(ele => ele.key == event.target.dataset.id);
        foundelement.Date = event.target.value;
        this.ERDHRecords = [...this.ERDHRecords];
        this.saveMessage = true;
        
        //console.log(' ==> ' +  JSON.stringify(this.ERDHRecords));
    }

    get todaysDate() {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' +  dd;
        return today
    }

    get modalityOptions() {
        return [
                 { label: 'In-person', value: 'In-person' },
                 { label: 'Virtual', value: 'Virtual' },
               ];
    }

    handleHoursChange(event){
        let foundelement = this.ERDHRecords.find(ele => ele.key == event.target.dataset.id);
        foundelement.Hours = event.target.value;
        this.ERDHRecords = [...this.ERDHRecords];
        this.saveMessage = true;
        this.sumHours();
        
        //console.log(' ==> ' +  JSON.stringify(this.ERDHRecords));
    }

    handleModalityChange(event){
        let foundelement = this.ERDHRecords.find(ele => ele.key == event.target.dataset.id);
        foundelement.Modality = event.target.value;
        this.ERDHRecords = [...this.ERDHRecords];
        this.saveMessage = true;
        //console.log(' ==> ' +  JSON.stringify(this.ERDHRecords));
    }

    sumHours(){
        let sum = 0;
        this.ERDHRecords.forEach((ERDH) => {
            sum += parseFloat(ERDH.Hours);
          });
          this.totalHours = sum;
    }

    
    handleSave(){
        
        
        const isInputsCorrect = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input,lightning-combobox')]
            .reduce((validSoFar, inputField) => {
                inputField.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputField.checkValidity();
            }, true);


        if (isInputsCorrect) {
            this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saving...';

            var toSaveList = [];
            this.ERDHRecords.forEach((element, index) => {
                
                let ERDH = { 'sobjectType': 'Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c' };
                ERDH.Id = element.Id;
                ERDH.Date__c = element.Date;
                ERDH.Hours__c = element.Hours;
                ERDH.Modality__c = element.Modality;
                console.log(ERDH);
                toSaveList.push(ERDH);
            })

            console.log(toSaveList);
            insertERDH({ERDHList : toSaveList,ERid: this.ERid})
            .then(() => {
                this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saved';
                this.saveMessage = false;
                console.log('Success Log');
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title : 'Success',
                        message : `Records saved succesfully!`,
                        variant : 'success',
                    }),
                )
                //this.accountTempRecords();
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.record = undefined;
                console.log("Error in Save call back:", this.error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Save';
                }, 3000);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### Apex Controller classes

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
global static list<Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c> getERDH(string ERid){
    list<Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c> ERDH = [select id, Engagement_Report__c, Date__c, Hours__c, Modality__c FROM Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c where Engagement_Report__c = :ERid];
    return ERDH;
}
@AuraEnabled
public static void addERDH(list<Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c> ERDHList,string ERid){
    system.debug(ERid);
    
    list<Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c> OldERDHs = getERDH(ERid);
    map<id,Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c> oldERDHMap = new map<id,Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c>();
    
    for(Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c ERDH: oldERDHs){
        oldERDHMap.put(ERDH.id,ERDH);
    }
    for(Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c ERDH: ERDHList){          
        if(ERDH.id != null && oldERDHMap.containskey(ERDH.id)){
            oldERDHMap.remove(ERDH.id);
        } else if (ERDH.id == null) {
            ERDH.Engagement_Report__c = ERid;  
        }
    }
    upsert ERDHList;
    delete OldERDHMap.values(); 
}
```

### HTML

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Engagement Dates and Hours" icon-name="standard:ERDHount">
<lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:add" slot="actions" label = "Add Row" onclick={addRow}></lightning-button-icon>
<lightning-button 
    label={toggleSaveLabel} 
    icon-name="utility:save" 
    slot="actions"
    onclick={handleSave}>
</lightning-button>


<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="">
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name"></div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Date">Date</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Hours">Hours</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Modality">Modality</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Action</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template for:each = {ERDHRecords} for:item = "ERDH" for:index="indexVar">
            <tr key={ERDH.key} class="slds-hint-parent">
                <td>
                    <div  >
                        <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-text-align_center">
                            <c-row-number-comp index={indexVar}></c-row-number-comp>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div  >
                        <lightning-input data-id={ERDH.key} required="true" type="date" name="date" label="Date" value={ERDH.Date} max={todaysDate} variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleDateChange}></lightning-input>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <div  >
                        <lightning-input data-id={ERDH.key} required="true" type="number"  formatter="decimal" step="any" name="hours" label="Hours" value={ERDH.Hours} variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleHoursChange}></lightning-input>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td  >
                    <div  >
                        <lightning-combobox data-id={ERDH.key} required="true" name="modality"  label="Modality" value={ERDH.Modality} variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleModalityChange}
                            options={modalityOptions}>
                        </lightning-combobox>
                       
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <a name={indexVar} data-id={ERDH.key} onclick={removeRow}>
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="delete" label="delete row" variant="label-hidden" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
            <td >
                
            </td>
            <td >
                <div   style="text-align: right;">
                    Total Hours:
                </div>
            </td>
            <td >
                <div   style="padding-left: 12px;">
                    {totalHours}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; color: red;">
                    <template lwc:if={saveMessage}>You have unsaved entries.<br/>Please save before clicking Next.</template>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <lightning-button 
                    label={toggleSaveLabel} 
                    icon-name="utility:save" 
                    slot="actions"
                    onclick={handleSave}>
                </lightning-button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Apex method `getERDH`, you are doing a query. It is returning a list of your `Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c` custom object, with the `Date__c` field selected.

That is why it is `Date__c` and not `Date`.

Comment: Right. But how do I get my ERDH records to behave like the Engagement_Report_Date_and_Hours__c fields? I thought that that was the work that this line was doing: @track ERDHRecord = {Id: RecordID_Field, Date : Date_FIELD, Hours : Hours_FIELD,Modality : Modality_FIELD, key : Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)};

Comment: Do I just need to standardize fields names to Date__c etc, and it will work without translation? I guess the examples I followed were using standard fields and standard objects so I got lead astray

Comment: That was it, and I finally got the other kinks worked out as well.